# Is there a way to remove / edit the metadata entry called "tag" from audio files without installing anything else?

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, tags, metadata

I would like to remove the piece of data of an audio-file which e.g. iTunes uses to display in the list of songs. It also uses this piece of data to sort them. I believe this piece of data is a part of the file's metadata, called `tag`.

I want to do this using a self-written Python script. I do not want to do this manually or by changing anything on my computer.

I found no way to do so using the stat module. I am using `Python 2.7.10`.

I am at this time interested in 2 file formats: mp3 and mp4. I have done some reading about the mp3 format here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3 . There it says: "The ID3v1 tag occupies 128 bytes, beginning with the string TAG 128 bytes from the end of the file." So I tried to just erease these bytes by overwriting them with 0.

Thanks to martineau I have improved my script:

```
import os
import sys

# had to use a different file which really contains a tag
vPath = "/Users/klausdorsch/Desktop/wegdamit/Armada.01.mp3" 
with open(vPath, "r+b") as vFile:  # Open existing file for reading and writing.
    vFile.seek(-128, os.SEEK_END)  # Seek 128 bytes before end of file.
    # Verify ID3v1 tag header starts there.
    tag = vFile.read(3)
    if tag == 'TAG':
        print 'found a tag!'
        # had to add brackets in the line below to avoid TypeError: 
        # unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
        vFile.write('\x00' * (128-3))  # Zero-out tag's contents.

sys.exit()
```

When I run it the first time, it outputs: "found a tag!", so a tag has been found. When I run it a second time, there is no such output, so the tag should have been removed. But when I open the file with iTunes, the tag's contents are still there.

Comment: You can do it in Python using the included `struct` module. Doing so will require a deep understanding of the file format and how to use the module to read different parts of the file and find the metadata you want. It may be fairly difficult if you're new to Python…

Comment: That was fast! Thanks! I have got the struct module on my computer and I have been using python for 15 years. However, I do not know so much about the file format and how to use the module to read different parts of the file and find the metadata I want. Could you provide some code?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a "write some codez for me" website. You haven't even defined precisely the file format you're interested in. Anyway, I suggest you give it a try yourself based on the module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) and whatever file format documentation you can find. I also _strongly_ suggest you upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: If you get stuck on something specific, feel free to ask a concrete question here. Hope your endeavor goes well. **Hints:** If you `open()` a file in binary mode, you can `seek()` to any position in it and read or write data. Data read can be parsed with the `struct` module and converted into equivalent Python data-types. The process can also be reversed.

Comment: Hello again! I am at this time interested in 2 file formats: mp3 and mp4. I have done some reading about the mp3 format here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3 . There it says: "The ID3v1 tag occupies 128 bytes, beginning with the string TAG 128 bytes from the end of the file."

Comment: Hi again, my original message has been chopped. The rest is: So I tried to just erease these bytes by overwriting them with 0.

This is the script I used:

 import os

 vPath="/Users/klausdorsch/Desktop/wegdamit/08ICanMakeYouAManReprise.mp3"
 vSize=os.path.getsize(vPath)
 vFile=open(vPath, "wb")

 for vPosn in range(vSize - 127, vSize):
  vFile.seek(vPosn)
  vFile.write('\x00')
 exit()

But this script only damaged the file making it impossible to use. I have no idea why and would greately appreciate any hlep!

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the code to it as it's very difficult to read in a comment — and that's how this Q&A site works. From what I am able to decipher of it, I can understand why it might damage a file...

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is you're opening the file in a mode that will first truncate it. The way and the position you're `seek()`ing to also doesn't seem right — and it only needs to do it once because reading and writing to a file automatically advances its internal current position.

Try doing it like this, which leaves the rest of the file intact and only zeros-out the contents of the ID3v1 tag if one is found.

```
import os
import sys

vPath = "/Users/klausdorsch/Desktop/wegdamit/08ICanMakeYouAManReprise.mp3"
with open(vPath, "r+b") as vFile:  # Open existing file for reading and writing.
    vFile.seek(-128, os.SEEK_END)  # Seek 128 bytes before end of file.
    # Verify ID3v1 tag header starts there.
    tag = vFile.read(3)
    if tag == 'TAG':
        vFile.write('\x00' * 128-3)  # Zero-out tag's contents.

sys.exit()
```